# Start application with modal login

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015, mahapps.metro

I'm using "Mahapps" for a WPF application, I want to start my application modal login starts.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Login();
    }

    private async void Login()
    {
        var resultado = await
            this.ShowLoginAsync("Login", "Ingresa los datos de Login",
                new LoginDialogSettings
                {
                    ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme,
                    EnablePasswordPreview = true,
                    UsernameWatermark = "Usuario",
                    PasswordWatermark = "Contraseña"
                });
    }
```

The problem is that throws me an error in doing so. But if I leave the code in a button if it works

```
private async void loginBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var resultado = await
            this.ShowLoginAsync("Login", "Ingresa los datos de Login",
                new LoginDialogSettings
                {
                    ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme,
                    EnablePasswordPreview = true,
                    UsernameWatermark = "Usuario",
                    PasswordWatermark = "Contraseña"
                });
    }
```

But I want you to just open the form load.
Thank you can guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening in dialog while still in the constructor of `MainWindow` cannot work, because the window is not created/visible yet.
Add a handler for the `Loaded` event and open the login dialog there.

Answer (score -1):

Change the declaration to public static void

Comment: That did but also generates an error, just leave it public, if I do too static failure

Comment: Ok so just public fixed the problem?

Comment: Excepción producida: 'System.NullReferenceException' en MahApps.Metro.dll

Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Comment: var resultado = await
                this.ShowLoginAsync("Acceso al Sistema", "Ingresa los datos de Login",
                    new LoginDialogSettings
                    {
                        ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme,
                        EnablePasswordPreview = true,
                        UsernameWatermark = "Usuario",
                        PasswordWatermark = "Contraseña"
                    });

Comment: change the header to Login() the function returns nothing and is in th same scope as the function calling it. Also, after InitializeComponent(); use Application.DoEvents();. Alternatively,you should call th login function in the form_load method

Comment: Application.DoEvents(); does not appear, it fails. but using the "form_load method" event worked. Thank you very much!!.